# Converting string value from spinner to boolean

Tags: java, android

Android Studio related question

Could someone enlighten me on how to read a spinner value (onItemSelectedListener) and parse it to boolean (For example as a YES/NO spinner)? Trying to do this to push the response to firebase. I have searched far and wide but to no avail.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For getting value in onItemClick you can call parent.getItemAtPosition(position), parent and position is parameters in onItemClick method

Comment: Sorry @Zoe...i put tags related to the question. New at this.

Comment: @LevonVardanyan so i could just call onItemClick method and return the position of the selection as boolean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String yesOrNoStr = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    boolean yesOrNo = yesOrNoStr.equals("YES");
  }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { }
});
```

Also assuming `position` is `0` if `"YES"` and `1` if `"NO"`, then you could alternatively do this:

```
boolean yesOrNo = position == 1;
```

Comment: No need to write `position == 1 ? true : false`, you can just write `position == 1`

Answer (score 0):

For getting item value in onItemSelected you can call

```
parent.getItemAtPosition(position)
```

After that, casting to boolean depends on what type of data you spinner keeps.
For string

```
String value = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
boolean result = "yes".equalsIgnoreCase(value);
```

For Integer values

```
Integer value = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
boolean result = value == 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I used your suggestion and tweaked it a bit, converting the spinner selection to String and using an If-Else construct to set the boolean value.